# Mousehover does not work - Selenium, Java, Chrome

Tags: java, selenium, mousehover

I am trying to automate the hover on a specified element, in my case is an specified office name. 
When I hover on an office the information of it should appear.
My problem is that when I run his code:

```
String officeId = findElement(designOfficesPosition, num).getAttribute(ConstantsFramework.ID);
WebElement office = getSupport().getDriver().findElement(By.id(officeId));


action.moveToElement(office).build().perform();
getSupport().pause(ConstantsFramework.TIME_OUT_10_SECONDS);
```

I don't get any errors but I don't see the information of the office. Am I missing something? Any ideas? Thanks

**UPDATE**

Here you can see a piece of the html:

```
<div id="officesListPreview">
<div class="roundBox previewOffice officesRotator">
<h3>Office information</h3>
<p class="numbers">
<div id="OPA-AT" class="officeContainer" style="display: none;">
<div id="BPO-BG" class="officeContainer" style="display: block;">
<a class="officeLink" href="http://www.bpo.bg/" target="_blank" style="">
<div class="detailsOffice">
</div>
<div id="BOIP-BX" class="officeContainer" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: have you tried action.moveToElement(office).build().perform();? please ensure you dont control your mouse during the script executed?

Comment: Can you post your html code of office information element.?

Comment: Try  `action.moveToElement(office).build().perform(); `

Comment: thanks for your answers, I just updated the question with the html, and I tried with:  action.moveToElement(office).build().perform() but it didn't work

Comment: Is it possible to give the link for the webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

What I was missing is that there are two classes **Actions** and **Action**. I was using just Action class

This works perfectly!!

```
WebElement home = driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div[@id='homePage']));

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
Action mouseOverHome = actions.moveToElement(home).build();

mouseOverHome.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try doing it via HasInputDevices interface.

```
RemoteWebElement homePage = (RemoteWebElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div[@id='homePage']));
            ((HasInputDevices)driver).getMouse().mouseMove(homePage.getCoordinates());
```